# Leap Year algorithm - Why 'or 400' instead 'and'?

Tags: c, algorithm

About Leap Year algorithm,

```
if( (year%4==0 && year%100!=0) || (year%400==0))
```

Why does it use "or" instead "and" `year%400==0`?

Comment: If you used `&&`, then *only* years divisible by 400 would be leap years. `year % 400 == 0` is an *exception* to the rule that century years are not leap years.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand.

Comment: Note that the expression in the question is computationally expensive — it checks whether every "non-leap year because not a multiple of 4" year is divisible by 400.  It works, but it does a lot of unnecessary 'year % 400` operations.  It would be better written as `if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0))`.  How often the extra division matters is open to debate — probably not very often.  But the revised code only checks whether the year is divisible by 400 if it is known to be divisible by 4 (and, indeed, only if i is also divisible by 100).

Comment: Thank you a lot @JonathanLeffler for your explication. I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Also, check out Wikipedia on leap years, and in particular the [Revised Julian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Revised_Julian_calendar).  It won't affect you in your lifetime, though (unless there's a startling medical breakthrough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about knowing the meaning of what leap year is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a leap year if the content of the first parenthesis (year%4==0 && year%100!=0) is true, OR if the second (year%400==0) is true.

Answer (score 0):

Leap year is a year which is an integer multiple of 4 (except for a year evenly divisible by 100 which is not a leap year unless evenly divisible 400). That is why we use the conditions:  `year%4==0 && year%100!=0` OR `year%400==0`

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar):

> "*Over a period of four centuries, the accumulated error of adding a leap day every four years amounts to about three extra days. The Gregorian calendar therefore drops three leap days every 400 years, which is the length of its leap cycle. This is done by dropping February 29 in the three century years (multiples of 100) that cannot be exactly divided by 400.*"

This is the explanation of the algorithm:
1 in 4 years is leap years is wrong. 
`year%4==0`, will be off by 3 days every 400 years.
We correct that by dropping 3 days using `(year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)`

givin the formula : `(year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)`